# Using Model.create when the parent class is not already saved

Tags: ruby, mongodb, sinatra, mongoid

I'm trying to create a `translate` keyword that create a class member working like a simple string but with different values, depending of the locale set.

Here is my code :

```
module Translate
  def translate(*attr_name)
    _field_name = attr_name[0]
    has_many :translations
    define_method(_field_name) do
      self.translations.where(key: _field_name, locale: I18n.locale).first
    end
    define_method("#{_field_name}=") do |params|
      self.translations.create!(key: _field_name, locale: I18n.locale, value: params.to_s)
    end
  end
end

class Translation
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :key, type: String
  field :value, type: String, default: ''
  field :locale, type: String

  belongs_to :productend
end

class Product
  include Mongoid::Document
  extend Translate
  translate :description
end
```

I'm getting this error :

```
Mongoid::Errors::UnsavedDocument: 
Problem:
  Attempted to save Translation before the parent Product.
Summary:
  You cannot call create or create! through the relation (Translation) who's parent (Product) is not already saved. This would case the database to be out of sync since the child could potentially reference a nonexistant parent.
Resolution:
  Make sure to only use create or create! when the parent document Product is persisted.
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/mongoid-3.1.7/lib/mongoid/relations/proxy.rb:171:in `raise_unsaved'
```

Comment: It's saying Product isn't saved yet, where is that created?

Comment: I'm creating it in the console with `p = Product.new` to test my code.

Comment: Right, try `p = Product.create`

Comment: Have you considered the possibility that `embeds_many :translations` might be more appropriate than `has_many :translations`?

Comment: I didn't new `embeds_many` (I'm really new in ruby programming) but it seem to be more appropriate !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is spelled out in the error message but you simply need to create a `Product` before you can try and create associated records.

Meaning this can't work:

```
product = Product.new
product.translations.create!
```

This can:

```
product = Product.create
product.translations.create!
```